# How to divide large string data in multiple pages or activity or fragments or flips

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to do a task but after wasting so much time still i didn't get any solution.

**Problem:** I am working on a news application, with flip effect. application shows a news content on first page, when user swipes bottom to top on screen an new flip opens and remaining news text content will be shown on next all flips.

The problem is, i set the initial text news on first screen on a text view, but when user swipe for more news, i am unable to detect how much text data i have shown on the first text, and how much i have remaining text data to set on next flip.

I searched many times that is there any function to get visible text on text view, but there is no solution for that, some logics are there but they are not working for me.

Thanks.

Comment: set ellipsize end for textview. after settext check your textview is ellipsized. if yes then it's text has been displayed.

Comment: have you used SQLite to store news string ? or anything else ?

Comment: right now i am testing it by static String

Comment: Are you doing wrap content on your TextView's height and width or providing dp values?

Comment: You could split that long text into two heterogeneous segments, one for the face and one for the back using `split` method of strings.

Comment: but on different different devices first page text varies, i set some characters for first screen and remaining for next but it will work only on one device, it will not work on other devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [public int getEllipsisStart (int line)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html#getEllipsisStart(int))
>
> Return the offset of the first character to be ellipsized away,
>   relative to the start of the line. (So 0 if the beginning of the line
>   is ellipsized, not getLineStart().)

This means that you can find out if your text has been ellipsized or not like this:

```
int ellipsisStart = mTextView.getLayout().getEllipsisStart() > 0;

if (ellipsisStart > 0) {
    // your text has been ellipsized
    // your text for the next page should be
    // String nextPageText = myString.subString(ellipsisStart);
} else {
    // your text fits on the first page
}
```

But remember that getLayout() will return null before the layout has been set, so you can use a ViewTreeObserver to find out if the layout has been laid out.

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = mTextview.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Layout layout = textview.getLayout();
        if ( layout != null) {
            // get your ellipsisStart
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry sir not working or i am doing something wrong.